# When I click to a page using IE with a galleria it doesn't load until I refresh

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, galleria

I have this site and the navigation is all accordion based, http://pearsonlyle.uwpistol.net/galleries/jan-baldwin/food-people/ . when i navigate to a page using the accordion, the page loads but the galleria on that page doesn't. however when I refresh that page, the galleria loads fine.

This site is meant to go live asap. It works on all other browsers I've de-activated the menu's and stripped back the galleria and it still isn't working.

Thing is about this is it's my fault I didn't test when I should have. Anyone know anything it might be?

Comment: Except it is slow in Chrome, it is working. Which link are you talking not working ?

Comment: Its working dear, just taking time to load. Reduce the size of image.

Comment: go to any link in IE say stylists > lesley dilcock > interiors/people, does a galleria load? it's not on the windows running on my mac, and my sisters pc laptop... panicking slightly lol :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok people I fixed it, I downloaded and replaced the galleria code with the new one, updated in Dec 2010, seems to work grand. Now I just need to try and fit testing into my day :( 
Thanks so much for the answers, quick and they did push me in the right direction :) xo